AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process'
Пишу радио бота на Python библиотеке Disnake и когда должна выполниться команда проигрывания аудио то бот пишет ошибку
@bot.slash_command(name="conn")
async def connect(ctx):
    
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    player = await channel.connect()
    player.play(FFmpegPCMAudio("http://s02.fjperezdj.com:8006/live", **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))

код функции
